# Define (or redefine) a type which the compiler will distinguish between (C++)

Tags: types

I've been trying to find a way to do the following in C++ but can't.  I assume there is no way but was interested because I would have thought this would be possible.

I'd like to define a type which is essentially a redefinition of an int but which can be distinguished between.  For example, an index which can access different overloaded functions (depending what it is an index of):

```
void ReturnSomeValue(IndexA id)
void ReturnSomeValue(IndexB id)
```

It's not necessary, but I thought it would be nice to avoid accidentally passing the wrong index to a different function which is designed for the other (thus triggering a compiler error 'no matching call for Function(IndexB)' and not a potentially baffling logical error).

I've tried using typedef

```
typedef int IndexA
typedef int IndexB
```

but it seems these are both ints with a different name as far as the compiler is concerned.

This will probably be possible using a class or a struct but will involve a lot of rewriting and seems a bit of an overkill for this simple issue.

Thanks for any help, I'd be interested to know if this was possible!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `typedef` alone won't work, but [here](http://www.ilikebigbits.com/blog/2014/5/6/type-safe-identifiers-in-c) is one solution using a class wrapper (see also the [reddit discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/2smwx1/type_safe_identifiers_in_c/) on it).

Comment: Thanks for your help. From the link and the corresponding reddit discussion I found the behaviour I was hoping would exist can be nearly replicated using enum class IndexA : int {}; so I've used that -- great for what I need it for!